# Regular Expressions in Play Framework URLS

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

I come from a django background. I just wanted to know how do you use regular expressions in URLS in the java Play! framework. I'm used to having this in django, so it would be a great help if anyone could give me a straight answer or point me in the right direction.

Comment: Regular expressions for what exactly? If you want to split a URL into different parts, you are better off using `URI`

Comment: For example, in django, you can send a get request, something like `/blog/(?P<slug_name>\w+)`, and that will allow only specific types of URLs to be accepted.

Comment: Unclear, sorry. What is clear from your example is that Django uses Python's regex engine ability to use named groups. What is not clear is what the URL looks like. Can it be, say, `foo://bar/blog/xx`? Because that will match your regex.

Comment: @fge: Yes, that will match the `regex`, but there can be more complex regexes, for example in the retrieval of a file, for example a time-stamp can be added before the actual name of a JPG file in accordance to the algorithm. You can use regexes more effectively there. The thing is, I want this functionality, of using regular expressions to Match URL requests. If its isn't available in the Play Framework, please say so.

Comment: I don't know whether this is available in the Play Framework as is; the thing is, if you have a string containing the URI, you can use URI to decompose the URI into its components (scheme, host, port, userauth, path, query string, fragment) and wotk from there. `URI` is extremely powerful. That said, I have never used the Play framework.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the [official documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/JavaRouting):  in the section `Dynamic parts with custom regular expressions` if it fits your needs.

Comment: Yes, yes it does. Thanks a million.